# How to change the "angle" of a quaternion but keep its direction. (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I did a lot of research but really can't find how I am supposed to use quaternion to do the following:

I have source orientation and a target orientation, and I am trying to find the quaternion of a specific angle (ex 10 degree) that goes from one orientation toward the other.

I'm trying to understand quaternions and also want to avoid gimbal lock, so I need an answer that doesn't need to convert to euler angles.

I know there is the Slerp function but its like a "percentage" instead of an angle. Also I'm not sure how to find the difference between source and target.

Basically I'm trying to do the following, but with quaternions instead of vectors:

```
Vector3 source, target; //Lets pretend they are defined
Vector3 vect_dir = target - source;
float vect_length = Mathf.Min(10f * Time.deltaTime, vect_dir.magnitude);
Vector3 answer = vect_dir.normalized * vect_length;
```

Any one knows how to do the same with quaternions? The idea is to put a speed value (10 in the example) of my choice.
Its very similar to using the Slerp function, except that I want a constant movement instead of a movement that goes fast and gradually slows down. I also would like to avoid using euler angles because of gimbal lock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Consider using  [`Quaternion.RotateTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html)

`Quaternion.RotateTowards` takes a `Quaternion` **from**, a `Quaternion` **to**, and a `float` **maxDegreesDelta**. Then, it returns whichever of these is closer to **from**:

1. The `Quaternion` between **from** and **to** that is **maxDegreesDelta** degrees away from **from**
2. **to**

So an example with `Quaternion`s that corresponds to yours could be written like:

```
Quaternion source, target; //Lets pretend they are defined
Quaternion reachedRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(source, target, 10f * Time.deltaTime);
```

If you need the difference between the reached point and `source`, you can do some quaternion math:

```
Quaternion answer = Quaternion.Inverse(source) * midpoint;
```

---

As an alternative, you could determine the difference between `target` and `source` and express that in angle (magnitude) and axis (direction) form with  [`Quaternion.ToAngleAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.ToAngleAxis.html):

```
Quaternion difference = Quaternion.Inverse(source) * target;
Vector3 differenceAxis;
float differenceAngle;
difference.ToAngleAxis(out differenceAngle, out differenceAxis);
```

And then, produce `answer` by capping `differenceAngle`:

```
Quaternion answer = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Mathf.Min(differenceAngle, 10f * Time.deltaTime), differenceAxis);
```

And if you want to find the rotation that results from "including" `answer` onto `source`, just multiply them (order is important):

```
reachedRotation = source * answer;
```

---

As a sidenote, your example with `Vector3`s could be written as:

```
Vector3 source, target; //Lets pretend they are defined
Vector3 answer = Vector3.MoveTowards(source, target, 10f * Time.deltaTime) - source;
```

Comment: That's a great answer! How would I get the intermediate values if I need them?  I think I can get the angle with Quaternion.Angle. But not sure how I would get the Quaternion difference between the two. (So the vect_dir in my example but for quaternions).

Comment: @Marc477 I added a bit about that to my answer. Let me know if that doesn't quite meet what you were looking for

Comment: @Marc477 I edited my answer to better answer your question as written

Comment: That's really great !